# Run each loop over div class in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am very new in react, so I am not able to understand how to run loop over div in React .Is it like same as we do in Jquery ?

```
<div class="muclass">
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="mybutton">Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div class="muclass">
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
      <<option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="mybutton">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

For that we do jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var totalCount =4;
$('.mybutton').click( function()
    {
        var elem = 'div';
        var hotel = $(this).closest(elem + '.muclass');
        var foundRooms =0;

        $('select.rooms', hotel).each(function() {       
                foundRooms += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        if(totalCount != foundRooms)
        {
         /*Throw an error */
         return
        }
    });
});
```

but in case of react how to do this validation if I have the same scenario  inside one component .

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `map` in react js instead of `each`. In the below code, I have create a array with `useState`. And I have used it to loop inside the component. You can see `loopVal.map` is used to loop the content.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [loopVal, setLoopval] = useState(["loop1", "loop2", "loop3"]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loopVal.map((loop) => {
        return (
          <div className="muclass">
            {loop}
            <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
              <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
            <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" className="mybutton">
              Click Me!
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div className="muclass">
        <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
          <option value="1">1</option>
        </select>
        <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <button type="button" className="mybutton">
          Click Me!
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you need any more clarification, You can create a react app using `npx create-react-app appname` and copy and paste the above code in the App.js file. You will be able to understand much better.

The one thing you should understand is Jquery is different and React Js is different. So I would suggest you not to keep Jquery in mind and learn React Js.

I have shared the sandbox link below,

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cookies-ws3sc0?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score -3):

You can use following syntax

```
{[1,2,3,4].map((val, index) => {
  // add condition here
  // if (condition) {
  // return null;
  // }

  return (
   <div class="muclass" data-count={val}>
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
      <<option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="mybutton">Click Me!</button>
 </div>)
 })
}
```

Comment: This structure is already implemented in the component . I want to validate that is user chose dat from dropdown which will be equal to 4 .